# A Compound word full of words

Tags: word, no-computers

This compound word is full of words.

> You might say it is made up of 2 words and you would be right. But the
>   first of the 2 words is also a compound word!
>
> You might say it is made up of 3 consecutive words ( I just said that)
>
> You might say it is made up of 4 consecutive words and again you will
>   be right.
>
> Then you will say that the first and the last of those 4 words when
>   put together is an english surname. Heard in a famous sitcom.

Any guess?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A possibility is

> Newspaperman

Made up of 2 words - the first of the 2 words is also a compound word, 3 consecutive words & 4 consecutive words

> Newspaper (news + paper) + man =  New + spa + per + man

An english surname. Heard in a famous sitcom.

> Seinfeld when being foiled by his antagonist [Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman_(Seinfeld)).

Comment: Amazing. What took you so long :) @Tom